# Does compactification of a Nambu-Goto string in one direction break Diff invariance?

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, compactification, diffeomorphism-invariance

Assume we have a Nambu-Goto action, in phase space, for a closed string. If I compactify one coordinate of the target space, do I reduce the diff invariance of the system.

We have
$$S=\int d^2\sigma \left(\dot{X}^mP_m-\lambda^+H_+-\lambda^-H_-\right)$$

where $H_\pm$ are primary constraints. They also generate infinitesimal diff transformations via Poisson brackets with the dof (i.e $X,P$).  I assume compactification $X^2\sim X^2+2\pi R$, thus boundary condition is $X^2(\sigma_1,\sigma_2+2\pi)=X^2(\sigma_1,\sigma_2)+2\pi R$ and the BC for rest of the dof is such that they are periodic under $\sigma_2\to\sigma_2+2\pi$ .

If I check $\delta S$ with I find a non-zero $\delta S$ where all of the non zero contributions are coming **only** from $X_2$ and $P_2$ terms. Thus it feels like  compactification reduces the diff invariance to non-compact coordinates. Am I  correct, or should I modify the bc further to have a fully diff invariant action.